# TypeScript does not narrow non-literal types

Tags: typescript

Say I have a simple parser:

```js
const str = "String to test";
let pos = 0;
function eat(
  ...args: (
    | [RegExp, (result: RegExpExecArray) => boolean]
    | [string, (result: string) => boolean]
    | [string[], (result: number) => boolean]
  )[]
) {
  const oldPos = pos;
  for (const [test, callback] of args) {
    if (test instanceof RegExp) {
      test.lastIndex = pos;
      const match = test.exec(str);
      if (match) {
        pos = test.lastIndex;
        if (callback(match)) return true;
        break;
      }
    } else if (typeof test === "string") {
      if (str.substr(pos, test.length) === test) {
        pos += test.length;
        if (callback(test)) return true;
        break;
      }
    } else {
      const temp = test.findIndex(item => str.substr(pos, item.length) === item);
      if (temp != -1) {
        pos += test[temp].length;
        if (callback(temp)) return true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  pos = oldPos;
  return false;
}
if (eat(
  [/string/iy, result /* RegExpExecArray */ => {
    // ...
    return true;
  }],
  [["foo", "bar"], result /* number */ => {
    // ...
    return true;
  }]
)) console.log("Matched");
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOMC8MBEBlK8CWYDmMUIhAptKgNwBQANibAA4gTIwAM1AZgK5jBTZwMEgEMoACiowYAOjkj4eCAC4Yk6dIA+MANoAlEngCiADwYAaNfDLcaUVQeNnTJYAEF48EQE8AlMgA+GAAjEBA6ETAAXSkNbR0EXDxLcWsIW3s4LCT-JCDQ8NFo2K1dRPwdKJS0jNUwbgBbYJJ4XPywiOLpX0qqfwBvWNBIWHCAEwAFZlYmCGppThBEcWHoXSgyKEtgERoaYJFgAGsomBBOGAUlAZKYbAvxDbXcaEjgEnOYR1MGG40NJ5QGQ0ETQACSYDGJBMM2Y83+MFWsAaYmAAAtWICZNDXOIEL54f97moUVB0X8EdJZpjNsDQVAIVCTISEcSVrt9ocjuJSeT-NYoNx4GBCPBuCQWf9gtYREdJTAAL63BXCGgQEh3B5QbwMD4XQHIJAoVDlPCoClEh4IGTpYIIcSzSxYuj4KBo3JG0jQC0I6kAahQzpIrrR8ukbJ2ewOx0em18-PoQpFWHFYZCMrlt2kSv+KpIao1g0pSNIDQYNOgMk4uDGjOh4mwGwagSy8Bt3DtWAdzEsjZIDWBwbwbo9KD7DQJWc1aib5YAhCgALQARh9-39gc2OlnUUHIbTEY50e5s-jMAFSdFqan0mlokzlJzGifT+pKHGUzmsQvwpgnF26rUEqbKiBIsQ6AA9KaEHYN4lg1HYMAQQAVF8hg-C47ieD4MDIRBLZFhoEH4XIMi3D+yZihKsQKlU4E6KgiwgKglioAc8CoFU542IhKEwPUTQtLh+F5DAhHSMRshyORia-im1HZjEZ6rIUwIgHg4ioAAsqiaIkGM5oUEAA)

I don't know anyway to correct define the type of `args` to make the compiler happy.

---

I know that I can just case `match`, `test`, `temp` (the `result`s pass to the `callback`) `as never`, but this doesn't infer the type of `result` when the method itself is called either.

An alternative method would be adding a string tag before like this:

```js
function example(arg: ["string", string, number] | ["boolean", boolean, bigint]) {
    if (arg[0] === "string") {
        Math.floor(arg[2]); // compiler happy
    }
}
```

But it'll be verbose when a call is made. (It doesn't seem to work in my case either.)

I also tried generics and function overload, but either it does not work, or it does not suit my needs (I am mixing 3 types of argument arrays when calling the function).

---

Any ideas about it? Should I post this issue to the [issues page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) on GitHub in case it's a bug?

([Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCnQCcBzALkQG0BnKYmMUgGkTBEwCNliBdRAD7VOcOPnRhWnGKUZReASkQBvAFCINiGMEQEoAT2zI4OkqSoAGfgF5biAER0GTe0rWaPiALLooACwA6YFxRYiIyKgBGRQBudU0AX1Uk0EhYBBQMHHwAJnCKagAlZFIAUVRsVgJiZBoQXChKYrKK8uQIAEFiYnR9JWsAPkQANzgYABN+IVp6RhZdGrqGynYuHn6h0YnFFXiNbV0DIxNEM0sbO0dZlzc9zzPoggsFOI8klPBoeCQ0LDxkADM+UoM2c81W3D4gmEonEkkQ0lkYHktw8qS+GRgNAAytdSAAVED-PS1RqnMB9ShQUlaGjUJxzVgSfT8dyeDQ1KAgYhII7GHTUujnRC2awOBkuV6JO4HAhY3FgwnEswKVHs7y+QLBUL5KKxO7vVTo9I-LL-AAswKKJXKlQWtXqZOatranW6vQ2IzGk2hoMZ9qWZIh6xFm29OzZGmN31pCrmSvwJLolGZCipNKx9LxTIprLuHk53N5hn5iEFUGFovFePsUo0SQ8svleIThBVavZD14TxeBuSQA) is a TypeScript Playground with some more experiments on this issue.)

Comment: I believe this issue is already exists. I think you should use typeguards like here https://tsplay.dev/NBPnzW .

Answer (score 0):

You can build a type guard that, with some additional help, can make your code type-safe:

```ts
const str = 'String to test';
let pos = 0;

type TCallback<TTest, TParam> = [TTest, (result: TParam) => boolean];

function isCallback<TTest, TParam>(
    callback: TCallback<any, any>,
    validate: (test: TTest) => boolean
): callback is TCallback<TTest, TParam> {
    return validate(callback[0]);
}

function eat(
    ...args: (
        | TCallback<RegExp, RegExpExecArray>
        | TCallback<string, string>
        | TCallback<string[], number>
    )[]
) {
    const oldPos = pos;
    for (const arg of args) {
        if (isCallback<RegExp, RegExpExecArray>(arg, (test) => test instanceof RegExp)) {
            const [test, callback] = arg;
            test.lastIndex = pos;
            const match = test.exec(str);
            if (match) {
                pos = test.lastIndex;
                if (callback(match)) return true;
                break;
            }
        } else if (isCallback<string, string>(arg, (test) => typeof test === 'string')) {
            const [test, callback] = arg;
            if (str.substr(pos, test.length) === test) {
                pos += test.length;
                if (callback(test)) return true;
                break;
            }
        } else if (isCallback<string[], string>(arg, (test) => test instanceof Array)) {
            const [test, callback] = arg;
            const temp = test.findIndex((item) => str.substr(pos, item.length) === item);
            if (temp != -1) {
                pos += test[temp].length;
                if (callback(temp)) return true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    pos = oldPos;
    return false;
}

if (eat(
    [/string/iy,
    (result: RegExpExecArray) => {
        // ...
        return true;
    }],
    [['foo', 'bar'],
    (result: number) => {
        // ...
        return true;
    }]
))
    console.log('Matched');
```

Note that I'm passing the parameters' types to the `isCallback` there, that way, you're telling TypeScript to assume the return type is what you just confirmed it to be.

I'm also extracting the `test` and `callback` variables *in* the typeguarded condition, as that's the only place where we're sure which of the options it's typed as.